# I don't know what s[::-1] is in Python

Tags: python

I keep seeing this: `s[::-1]` in Python and I don't know what it does.  Sorry if this is a question but I'm new to python and generally programming.

Comment: it's not pythonic, but it is python.

Comment: How is it non-pythonic?  It's the most pythonic way to reverse a sequence that I'm aware of ...

Comment: `reversed` is much clearer.

Comment: This question title will not help others when searching this kind of problem.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper `reversed` and `s[::-1]` serve different purposes. You should use the former when you want to *iterate* through a sequence backwards, but use the latter when you actually want the reversed sequence. For strings, using the slice notation is almost always correct. Using `reversed` for strings is actually pretty difficult, you would have to do something like `''.join(reversed(s))`, which is definitely not pythonic.

Comment: @RogerFan: Or, if you don't know what type something is, but want the same type reversed, `s[::-1]` does what you want; otherwise you need something like `(''.join if issubclass(type(s), str) else type)(reversed(s))`—which still doesn't work for `bytes`/`bytearray`/`unicode`, `pd.DataFrame`, and lots of other seuqences and sequence-like types in the stdlib and popular modules…

Answer (score 5):

It reverses a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-sequence) using slicing.

```
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> s[::-1]
'olleh'
```

The slice notation `[]` is a way to get a subset of some iterable container. It has the syntax

```
[start : stop : step]
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) for more details.

Comment: Any sliceable object, not just a string.

Comment: You are correct, updated.

Comment: The update's not quite right - not all iterables can be sliced. I think sequence is the most general term: https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-sequence

Comment: Updated again! One of these days I'll use the right term.

Comment: It is admittedly an obscure subject unless you're working with the collections abstract base classes: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes

Comment: It gets even more confusing language hopping too, because 75% of my day-to-day programming at work is C++, so I have to be careful about Python "list" vs C++ "std::list", etc. Some colloquial terms have technical meanings in other languages and vice versa.

Comment: And technically speaking you can overload the slice notation if you want. But... you probably shouldn't do that.

Comment: "… some iterable container …" is still wrong. Something can easily be iterable, and a container, but not a sequence. Like, say, `dict`.

Comment: @WayneWerner: Well, you definitely _should_ do it if you're trying to build a custom sequence, or a not-quite-sequence like a numpy array or pandas frame…

Answer (score 0):

Slicing is an operation that gives you some elements out of a sequence.

`s[a:b:c]` means "the items starting at `a`, stopping at `b`, with a step of `c`".

If you have `s[::-1]` that means "the whole sequence, going backwards".